# Ipv6 regarding fatalException when using datagram sockets

Tags: android, sockets, datagram

I am using nsd for connecting two Android devices via WiFi. Nsd service listen for incoming data from clients with datagram server socket and provides its local ip (v4) address and port. On client side I get exception with ipv6 issue, when it's trying to send data with datagram sockets, using ip address and port, provided by service.

Here's exception title

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Connected to android-a1b172a0c524a2b1.attlocal.net/192.168.1.232:42410, not android-a1b172a0c524a2b1.attlocal.net/2600:1700:d2c1:1b90:234:daff:fe18:624f:42410
```

It refers to

```
java.nio.DatagramChannelImpl.send (DatagramChannelImpl.java:249)
```

I can't find a reason, why it's happening. It works well on most wifi networks, but crashes on one specific wifi.